# Is Warlock a male-only term?

Tags: harry-potter

According to the [HP wiki, Warlock is a term for a particularly advanced wizard](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Warlock).  The examples given are all male.  The standard English use of the word is definitely male gendered.  Can witches achieve this title?  Is there a female equivalent title?

Comment: HP Wiki basically made that up by extrapolating from sparse data and [jumping to an unsupported conclusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRxqY4wuTHw).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is a resounding "***MAYBE***".

1. The only definition (from JKR's footnote to Dumbledore's notes to the tale from *Beedle the Bard* is):

   > The term "warlock" is a very old one. Although it is sometimes used as interchangeable with "wizard," it originally denoted one learned in dueling and all martial magic. It was also given as a title to wizards who had performed feats of bravery, rather as Muggles were sometimes knighted for acts of valor. By calling the young wizard in this story a warlock, Beedle indicates that he has already been recognized as especially skillful at offensive magic. These days wizards use "warlock" in one of two ways: to describe a wizard of unusually fierce appearance, or as a title denoting particular skill or achievement. Thus, Dumbledore himself was Chief Warlock of the Wizengamot. - JKR

   Now, you **can** interpret this to mean male only since she keeps saying "wizard" and never "witch". But she also uses "wizarding world" as a gender-neutral term so I would be very hesitant to draw any conclusion here.

   - It's worth remembering that on one hand, Wizarding World is stuck in 15-16th century British culture and shares at least some of its attendant gender attitudes - **but clearly not all**. Female witches seem to have a lot more power/influence (Bellatrix, female Aurors, Nevilles Grandmother, Prof. McGonagle, former Hogwarts headmistress [Dilys Derwent](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dilys_Derwent#cite_note-SBT-1)) but possibly not fully equal (no female Ministers or big bosses I can observe, more housewife+working husband arrangements ala Weasleys or Malfoys - bet they love that I put them in the same sentence :)
2. Some evidence can be interpreted to point to "male-only":

   - There is no mention of female warlocks in any HP canon sources (books/interviews/PotterLess). See the full list below.

     Confirmed by searching full interview archives, full book texts and full Pottermore reference.
   - Out of universe, warlock is semantically a male term in pretty much any usage ([M-W definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warlock), [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/warlock)).
   - Above-mentioned definition talks about "wizards" only, which is mostly a male term. But it can also be used gender-neutrally in-universe.
3. Having said that, there is also no mention of any reasonable definition of what a "warlock" is in-universe aside from the one above, and too few examples of the term's usage to be enough to jump to a conclusion.

   And some examples **may** include females in theory - see notes below.

   The full list of examples I can think of:

   - Obviously, Dumbledore's official title of the Chief Warlock of Wizengamot.

     We aren't shown any chief female Warlocks, however. But we don't know of many chief warlocks, period.
   - "Warlock's Convention of 1709" from PS where they outlawed owning Dragons.

     This one is ambiguous. Presumably, witches would have also attended the convention? We just don't know either way.
   - Father of Angus Buchanan, author of *My Life As A Squib* book and Scottish Rugby player. Clearly male.
   - Brutus Malfoy's "Warlock at War" anti-Muggle periodical. This is gender neutral but it isn't hard to conclude that Brutus was, in a modern parlance, likely a *male chauvinist pig* :)
   - *The Warlock's Hairy Heart* from Tales of Beadle the Bard. Clearly male.

Comment: This makes sense.  The wizarding world inherits many cultural issues, including sexist language, from the muggle world, so this is just another example.

Comment: @zipquincy - see my update to #1

Comment: There are female headmasters among the portraits in Dumbledore’s office, are there not? And McGonagall is of course also headmaster. There may also be female Ministers for Magic—we only hear about four (five?) in total. There are definitely female heads of various ministerial departments (Susan Bones comes to mind). But these are all just minor points. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - There was a female portrait (one of the witch who was sent to St. Mungos) but I don't recall if she was a HeadMistress. And yes, my main point is that there's not enough data for firm conclusions :)

Comment: Are there portraits in that office that _aren’t_ headmasters? I thought only people the school itself considered worthy headmasters got their picture on the wall there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - see last edit

Answer (score 0):

From the Oxford English Dictionary:

A man who practices witchcraft; a sorcerer.

Origin : Old English wǣrloga ‘traitor, scoundrel, monster’, also ‘the Devil’, from wǣr ‘covenant’ + an element related to lēogan ‘belie, deny’. From its application to the Devil, the word was transferred in Middle English to a person in league with the Devil, and hence a sorcerer. It was chiefly Scots until given wider currency by Sir Walter Scott.

OK, so we have nearer to the surface of the "present" Now, A man who practices witchcraft; a sorcerer." // Man / sorcerer / witchcraft.

Further back in time we have monster, in league with the Devil. FYI, Satan is the condition of pure False, the absolute denial of truth, so any gender assignment at all would be a false attribution. In short, the closer one gets to Satan, the more one denies the reality of one's own gender, which is why most religious folk view homosexuals / transgenders as an abomination before God (generally considered as the Supreme opposite of False.)

Comment: So is a warlock male only?

Comment: This doesn't really answer whether "warlock" is exclusively male in the "Harry Potter" universe.